# Definite integration but no indefinite integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider the following integral:

```
Integrate[(Sin[x] + Cos[x])^a Sin[x]^b Cos[x]^c, x]
```

On my system Mathematica 11 just returns the input back, which suggests that this integral does not appear in the database.

However, if we add definite boundaries to the integral:

```
Integrate[(Sin[x] + Cos[x])^a Sin[x]^b Cos[x]^c, {x, 0, Pi/2}]
```

all of a sudden the integral evaluates to a bunch of hypergeometric functions.

How can this be? If Mathematica does not know the indefinite integral, how can it obtain the definite one? Is it possible to still somehow extract the indefinite integral from Mathematica?

Comment: Are `b` and `c` nonnegative integers?

Comment: Some definite integrals can be evaluated without the fundamental theorem of calculus.  Some techniques are usually taught in a first course on complex analysis.

Comment: @CarlWoll `b,c` are complex numbers. But if something non-trivial can be said about the integer case, I would be very interested in that as well!

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I am familiar with residues, but I can't see any residues in this example. Perhaps you know how to apply complex analysis in this case? I'd be very interested to know!

Comment: With `Sin[x] = Sqrt[t]`, `Cos[x] = Sqrt[1-t]`, then some of these formulas seem to apply: http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6

Comment: @MichaelE2 The term `(Sin[x]+Cos[x])^a` becomes `(Sqrt[t]+Sqrt[1-t])^a` which does not seem to appear in these representations. Maybe I am missing some step?

Comment: *Mathematica* probably does some algebra, don't you think?  (I don't have time to ***solve*** it for you, but I think it's a decent lead.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Indeed, I've been looking at Hypergeometric function representations for days before asking the question here. I certainly do not expect anyone to invest that much time to help...

Comment: for `b=0` MMA 11.2 spit enormous expression with `AppellF1` function

Comment: Really more of a math question as to why some definite integrals can be found in absence of indefinite counterparts.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Except, instead of "why" I am particularly more interested in "how, using Mathematica".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem arises from the a.

Restricting the a - values to positive integers, you can get a solution for the indefinite integral with arbitrary b and c.

Write the a-term as binomial sum and multiply with the b-term and c-term:

```
g[x_, a_, b_, c_] := 
       Sum[Binomial[a, k] Sin[x]^(k + b) Cos[x]^(a - k + c), {k, 0, a}]
```

General solutions for the sincos-term

```
sincos = Integrate[Sin[x]^(k + b) Cos[x]^(a - k + c), x]

(*   -((Cos[x]^(1 + a + c - k) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (1 - b - k), 1/2 (1 + a + c - k), 
         1/2 (3 + a + c - k), Cos[x]^2] Sin[x]^(1 + b + k) (Sin[x]^2)^(
         1/2 (-1 - b - k)))/(1 + a + c - k))   *)
```

The desired integral is then

```
int[x_, a_, b_, c_] := Sum[Binomial[a, k] sincos, {k, 0, a}]
```

Answer (score 3):

For the case where `b` and `c` are nonnegative integers, you could do the following:

```
f[d_, e_, n_] = Integrate[(d Sin[x] + e Cos[x])^n, x];

int[a_, b_Integer?NonNegative, c_Integer?NonNegative] := Simplify[
    Derivative[b, c, 0][f][1, 1, a+b+c]/Pochhammer[a+1, b+c]
]
```

For example:

```
r = int[3,2,1];
r //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{(\sin (x)+\cos (x)) \left(\sqrt{\sin (2 x)+1} (15 \sin (x)-7 \sin (3 x)-17 \cos (x)-3 \cos (3 x)+2 \cos (5
>    x))-24 \sin ^{-1}\left(\cos \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\right)\right)}{96 \sqrt{\sin (2 x)+1}}$

Check:

```
D[r, x] //Simplify
```

> Cos[x] Sin[x]^2 (Cos[x] + Sin[x])^3

Comment: Interesting approach in that case!